# WebAuthenticationBroker returns a UserCancel WebAuthenticationResult on a successful Facebook authentication

Tags: facebook, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

Using the WebAuthenticationBroker for Single Sign On in a Windows Phone Store app (WinRT / WP8.1), i use the following code to engage the Facebook login process :

```
string redirectUri2 = Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().AbsoluteUri;
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient();
Uri loginUri = fb.GetLoginUrl(new {
            client_id = FacebookAppID,
            redirect_uri = redirectUri2,
            response_type = "token",
            scope = FacebookScope,
            display = "popup"
});
WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(loginUri, new Uri(redirectUri));
```

In the ContinueWebAuthentication(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args) callback, the WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus I get is UserCancel, even on a successful sign in.

Trace of the last response from Facebook :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Facebook-API-Version: v2.0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
P3P: CP="Facebook does not have a P3P policy. Learn why here: http://fb.me/p3p"
Set-Cookie: wd=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=-1413367561; path=/;    domain=.facebook.com; httponly
X-FB-Debug: {edited out}
Date: Wed, 15 Oct 2014 10:06:02 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 411

<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="ms-app:\/\/s-1-15-2-908865707-3825634006-813379085-3082126904-2549935584-1522363559-xxxxxxxxxx\/#access_token={edited out}&expires_in=5113018";</script>
```

What is going on with the WebAuthenticationBroker ?

Additional information on the issue : the date/time/timezone on the phone are correct.

Comment: What is the resultant loginUri?   I don't think you need that 2nd parameter to AuthenticateAndContinue.  I looked at some working code I have and I do not pass in 2nd param.  Here is my Uri:

"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXX&display=popup&response_type=token&redirect_uri=XXXAppURIXXX"

Comment: Thank you Bret, the error was too obvious for me to spot, there was a mismatch between both redirectUrl.
I removed the 2nd param and everything went back to normal.